# Hypernym for "webinars" and "podcasts"

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I'm looking for a single word that describes both *webinars* and *podcasts*. Any ideas?

Comment: Webinars are generally intended to be two-way communication (unless you're talking about a recording of the webinar that gets posted after the fact); podcasts are one-way.  The only thing they have in common is the Internet, so...

Comment: I agree with MT_Head. This question seems analogous to asking for a single word to describe a discussion and a broadcast. -1

Comment: I'm not sure that a webinar is a two-way thing.. That would be a conference. A webinar (online seminar) is surely one person addressing a crowd? Thus, both Podcast and Webinar are for broadcasting some kind of information. Therefore, I could go with Online Broadcast, Online Media or something similar.

Comment: @Karl: From what I know, some webinars are largely one-way, but most have the opportunity for at least some two-way communication, even if it's through a moderator.  Furthermore, some are webinars are designed to foster much two-way interaction, particularly when the audience is small.  All that said, "webinar" is a relatively newly-coined term, and may mean different things to different people.

Comment: I can't help but feel that the question would be easier to answer if the original posted explained what they regard as being the common and differentiating features of "webinars" and "podcasts".  Most of the suggestions in the answers thus far would be unsuitable in that if you used them without first explaining the context, it would not be clear what you are referring to, meaning you might as well just have said "webinars and podcasts".  It's worth noting that two similar words will not necessarily have a hypernym and as always context is king.

Comment: @J.R. , thank you. I have learned something there.

Comment: @Christi makes a good point about similar/related words not necessarily having a hypernym, especially possible with such relatively new words.

Comment: Yes, I should have definitely provided some context! The hypernym is to be used as a navigation label on a website--it'll link to a page where the user can find both webinars and podcasts. I'll be going with @J.R.'s suggestion: Webcasts. Thanks for your all comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest the word ***broadcast***.  A few decades ago, it was used as a hypernym for radio and television shows, and many dictionaries still explicitly list those media in their definition of *broacast*.  However, in today's world – where people make phone calls over the internet – media boundaries are becoming more blurred than ever; I don't think anyone would have trouble expanding the boundaries of *broadcast* beyond radio and television.  You could even specify ***internet broadcast*** if you felt like *broadcast* alone was not suited for your purposes.  ***Webcast*** might be yet another alternative.

A *webinar* would be a two-way internet broadcast medium, while a *podcast* would a one-way internet broadcast medium.

Interestingly enough, the word *broadcast* was borrowed from agriculture, so it wouldn't hurt to bend it a little bit more than it's already been bent.

Comment: Well some words are like prisoners in the bath, they don't feel comfortable to bend to get the slippery soap if you know what I mean JR ;-) Actually I have considered *broadcast* too, although I don't find meaning for large group of people talking in there, speaking about specific problems (webinar), so I left it.

Comment: @speedyGonzales: You make a good point about webinars, where most (if not all) of the attendees contribute. However, the resulting discussion is still broadcast to all the participants, so, for that reason, I think the word fits nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [propagate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/propagate). The idea is that both webinars and podcasts spread information over the internet. The noun is [propagation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/propagation).

Comment: I don't think this works. The OP s looking for a noun, you've provided a verb.

Comment: I have edited my answer, are you happy now darling *winks*

Comment: You would call a webinar a *propagation*? I don't think it's a very intuitive choice. Not entirely impossible though.

Comment: Remember that the Italian word for **propagation** is *propaganda*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in Italian 'propaganda' is used mainly with meanings of 'advertising' (commercial) or 'electioneering' (politic).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a term like **online dissemination,** with the emphasis on **online**.