# Hypernym for image, video, and audio

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I want to put all my images, videos, and audio files from my camera in only one folder on my computer. What should be the name to give to that folder?

Comment: Remotely related: [Hypernym for “audiobook”, “podcast”, “speech”, etc.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47251/hypernym-for-audiobook-podcast-speech-etc), [Hypernym for “webinars” and “podcasts”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73905/hypernym-for-webinars-and-podcasts)

Comment: *What should be the name to give to that folder?* There is no requirement for any particular name to be given to any folder. As long as you know that photos, videos go into it, that should be enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use [*media*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/medium), plural of medium, meaning:

> A specific kind of artistic technique or means of expression as determined by the materials used or the creative methods involved: *the medium of lithography*.

Comment: Yes, but this word may give the meaning that these files may have been retouched or edited. I need to use a name that indicate that it has not been touched. I tried the word **shots** but it can't be for audio. I thought about the word **recordings** but it is not good for photos

Comment: Use media as a noun-modifier: _media files_. _Data files_ would include Word docoments etc.

Comment: if your concern regarding "media" is the issue of having retouched content, why not use "raw media" or something like that? You could also stick with "actuality" I guess.

Comment: That would be "Raw media", meaning unprocessed. The hypernym "media" covers your original request, and you now need to qualify it to restrict the scope.

Comment: I found **My Media** the best choice. Thanks for all

Comment: I use the "media" folder to house the individual media type sub-folders on my personal website now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you say "from my camera"?

That is more meaningful in context than the list of file types. Calling the folder "***FromMyCamera***" makes more sense and can be fun, try it.

After all, Windows default folder is *My Documents*.

You have the option of calling the folder "***Raw***" if you like, except that, technically RAW is itself a file format in photography.

Answer (score 1):

My ideas for next time:

- Virgin Media
- OriMedia - Original Media
- Unfiltered Media
- Media Station
- 1st Media
- First Media
- Media1
- MediaOne
- Pure Media

Or use a different central word completely:

- Gallery
- Digital

Answer (score 1):

> [**Multimedia**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia)

used to be the word, although it is now rather démodé.